# Problems on vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $E$ a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space of finite dimension $n$, $\mathcal{V}$ a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(E)$ such that $$\forall u\in\mathcal{V}\setminus \{0\},u\in\mathcal{GL}(E)$$

a) Show that $\dim\mathcal{V}\leq n$

b) When $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$, show that $\dim\mathcal{V}\leq1$

c) When $E=\mathbb{R}^2$, give an example of a space $\mathcal{V}$ with dimension $2$.

d) Suppose that $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$. Show that if $\dim\mathcal{V}\geq2$ then $\dim E$ is even.

EDIT : questions  a,b,c have been answered in the comments/chat. I still need help with d).

---

For c), I thought that $\mathcal{V}=\{u(x,y)=(a\cdot x+b\cdot y,a\cdot y-b\cdot x)\mid a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ worked well.

I however have not found, after searching some time, how to do a),b) and d) (which it would seem are independent).

Could I get some hints for those three questions?

Comment: What is L(E)?  Also in your first inline equation, should both variables be u?

Comment: For $a)$ consider the subspace $W$ of $L(E)=M_n(\mathbb{K})$ formed by all matrices with the first row null. Consider $V\cap W$. For $b)$, if $A,B\in V$ then $A-\lambda B=(AB^{-1}-\lambda Id)B\in V$. Can you choose the right $\lambda$ to make $A-\lambda B$ singular?

Comment: @user148177 $\mathcal{L}(E)$ :  linear applications from $E$ to $E$. As for the first inline what do you mean ? u is not a space, $\mathcal{V}$ is.

Comment: @Daniel Why do you have $\mathcal{L}(E)=M_n(\mathbb{K})$ ?

Comment: @Hippalectryon I should have written $L(E)$ is isomorphic to $M_n(\mathbb{K})$ instead of $L(E)=M_n(\mathbb{K})$. Since $E$ is finite dimensional, we can choose a basis for $E$ and represent every linear transformation acting on $E$ as a matrix of order $n$.

Comment: @Daniel So when you wrote $V\cap W$, you meant $V\text{'s application's matrixes}\cap W$ ?

Comment: @Hippalectryon Consider your set $V$ as a subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{K})$ and $W$ is the subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{K})$ formed by matrices with the first row null. Notice that $\dim(W)=n^2-n$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17352/discussion-between-hippalectryon-and-daniel).

Comment: Note that your choice for c) won't work; what if $a$ or $b$ is zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I present all answers; partly gleaned from the comments.

Part a:

Let $f:E \to \Bbb K$ be a non-zero linear functional.
Let $W$ be the set $v \in \mathcal L(E)$ such that $f \circ v = 0$.

Note that $W$ is $n^2-n$ dimensional.  So, if $V$ is any subspace of $\mathcal L(E)$ with dimension greater than $n$, then there is a $v \in V$ with $f \circ v = 0$.

The conclusion follows.

Part b:

Consider $v,w \in \mathcal {GL}(E)$, and suppose that they are linearly independent.  We note that $\det(v - tw)$ is a polynomial on $t$.  By the fundamental theorem of algebra, there is a $t \in \Bbb C$ with $\det(v - tw) = 0$.  Thus, $v - tw$ is not invertible.  However, since $v,w$ are linearly independent, $v - tw \neq 0$.

It follows that no two-dimensional subspace of $\mathcal{L}(E)$ can satisfy the properties of $V$.

Part c:

Consider
$$
\left\{a \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1} + b\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}:a,b \in \Bbb R \right\}
$$

Part d:

Suppose that $E$ has odd degree.  Consider $v,w \in \mathcal{GL}(E)$.  We note that $\det(v - tw)$ is a polynomial on $t$ of odd degree.  Noting that any polynomial of odd degree has a real root, apply the argument from b.

Comment: what is $f$ in a) ?

Comment: @TheGame why the change in name?  In the example Daniel described, we have
$$
f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = x_1
$$
but the same argument works for any non-zero linear function $f:E\to \Bbb K$. I like writing it this way because now I don't have to specify a basis for $E$.

Comment: Don't worry about the name :) Why would $\dim W=\dim\ker f=n^2-n$ ? And didn't you mean $f:E\rightarrow E$ ?

Comment: $\dim(W) = \dim(\mathcal L(E,\ker f)) = n \cdot (n-1)$.  I indeed mean $f:E \to \Bbb K$.

Comment: But if $x_1\notin\mathbb{K}$, how can you have $f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = x_1$ ?

Comment: What?  $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is a vector in $\Bbb R^n$ (or $\Bbb K^n$ if you prefer) and each $x_i$ is an element of $\Bbb R$ (or $\Bbb K$).